# Derive Poisson distribution from probability per time of event

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a probability per time $\lambda$ that something (e.g. nuclear decay, random walk takes a step, etc.) happens.
It is a known result that the probability that $n$ events happen in a time interval of length $T$, is given by the Poisson distribution
$$P(n) = \frac{e^{-\lambda T} (\lambda T)^n}{n!} \, .$$ 
How do we prove this?

Comment: Ha - I saw this question and I thought "weird, I would have expected Daniel to know the answer to this". Then I scrolled down...

Comment: @Floris well it took me a while to get help on the integral...

Comment: I wrote an alternative that doesn't explicitly need integrals

Comment: @Floris yes, and I like the explicit relation to the binomial distribution, but I'm not sure that approach directly answers *this* question. Perhaps you can argue that many little time slices are like many low-probably attempts...

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I argue. In the limit of infinitely many time slices with the product $pN$ remaining constant, you are effectively making the transition from discrete to continuous - without ever appearing to integrate.

Comment: @Floris your post doesn't actually make that argument...

Comment: True. It didn't. Now it does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Probability distribution of time until next event

First we calculate the probability density that a time $t$ passes without any event happening.
Divide $t$ into $N$ small intervals each of length $dt = t/N$.
Defining $\lambda$ as the probability per time that the event occurs, the probability that no event occurs within any one short time interval is approximately $(1 - \lambda dt)$.
Therefore, the probability that no event happens in any of the intervals, but then *does* happen within an interval of length $dt$ right at the end of all the intervals is
$$\left( \prod_{i=1}^N \left( 1 - \lambda dt \right) \right) \lambda dt
= \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda t}{N} \right)^N \lambda dt
\stackrel{N\rightarrow \infty}{=} \lambda dt \exp \left( - \lambda t \right) \, .$$
In other words, given a starting time $0$, the probability *density* that no event has happened after a time $t$, but then happens right at $t$ is $\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$.

### Probability of multiple events

Now we ask the probability that we get $n$ events in the time interval $T$.
Suppose the first event happens at $t_1$, the second even happens at $t_2$, etc.
We therefore have a series of intervals
$$\{[0, t_1], [t_1, t_2], \ldots [t_n, T] \} $$
with events happening at the end of each interval.
The probability that our events occur in this way is
$$P(t_1, t_2, \ldots t_n) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda t_1) \lambda \exp(-\lambda (t_2 - t_1)) \cdots \lambda \exp(-\lambda(T - t_n)) = \lambda^n \exp(-\lambda T) \, .$$
Of course, any arrangement of $\{t_1, t_2, \ldots t_n \}$ such that $t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_n$ counts as an $n$-event arrangement, so we have to add up the probabilities of all these possible arrangements, i.e. the probability of $n$ events is
\begin{align}
P(n \text{ events})
&= \int_0^T dt_1 \int_{t_1}^T dt_2 \cdots \int_{t_{n-1}}^T dt_n P(t_1, t_2, \ldots t_n) \\
&= \lambda^n \exp(-\lambda T) \int_0^T dt_1 \int_{t_1}^T dt_2 \cdots \int_{t_{n-1}}^T dt_n
\, .
\end{align}
The multiple integral is the [volume of a right simplex and has value $T^n/n!$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume), so the final result is
$$P(n\text{ events}) = \frac{(\lambda T)^n \exp(-\lambda T)}{n!} $$
which is the Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda T$.

### Related

- [Direct evaluation of the simplex volume integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550852/nested-integral-volume-of-a-right-simplex/2553384#2553384)
- [Explicit computation for $n\in\{0, 1, 2\}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201670/from-exponential-distribution-to-poisson-distribution)

Comment: In your first derivation should $\lambda =1$ produce a probability density of 1 everywhere. If the probability density of the event happening at $t=t'$, and not before, is $\lambda e^{-\lambda t'} dt$ then $lambda = 1 \implies PDF(t)=e^{-t} dt$ then for any $t'$ we should get $ p(t') = \int_{0}^{t'} PDF(t) = -e^{-t'} + 1$ not $1$. _[mod edit to fix MathJax - DZ]_

Comment: @D.W. I don't understand this comment. $\lambda$ has dimensions of 1/time, so it can't have value 1. Could you clarify?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not criticising your answer, or suggesting you're wrong, I'm just trying to understand your derivation for myself. Isn't $\lambda$ the probability per unit time that something happens? What if something is guaranteed to happen? Wouldn't that correspond to a value of $\lambda = 1$ (the probability per unit time that the event happens is 1)

Comment: @D.W. I know you're not criticizing. No problem. In fact, the case you're describing where the event *always* happens even for infinitessimally small times would correspond to $\lambda \to \infty$. You can plug that into the various equations at any point and see how the results turn out. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm still a little confused as to how an event having a probability one of happening at all times corresponds to a probability per unit time that approaches infinity, but that's for me to ponder.

Comment: @D.W. Well, think about what "probability per time" means. It means that, for small enough times $dt$, the probability that a thing happens is $\lambda dt$. For any fixed value of $\lambda$, we can make $dt$ small enough such that $\lambda dt \to 0$. Therefore, the only way to make sure something *always* happens for *arbitrarily small $dt$* is to make $\lambda$ really big, i.e. infinite.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Yeah that makes complete sense now thank you

Comment: Excellent answer, but could you modify it to explain what lambda is before you use it?  I'm still a little confused at the equation that it first appears in.

Comment: @user1717828 see edited first paragraph, and please let me know via comment if it's ok now.

Comment: I've accepted my own answer because it had the highest number of votes. The other answers are excellent as well so check them out. I especially like [leonbloy's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/372652/31790).

Answer (score 8):

The Poisson distribution describes the probability of a certain number ($n$) of unlikely events ($p\ll 1$) happening given $N$ opportunities.

This is like doing a very unfair coin toss $N$ times, with the probability $p$ of the coin turning up heads. The number of heads would follow the binomial distribution:

$$P(n|p,N) = ~^{N}C_n~p^n (1-p)^{N-n} =\frac{N!}{(N-n)!~n!} p^n (1-p)^{N-n}$$

Now it remains to prove that when $N\rightarrow \infty$ and $p\rightarrow 0$ while $Np\rightarrow \lambda T$, that the above converges to the known result. In essence, I argue that when you make the number of opportunities tend to infinity, you go from a discrete to a continuous approach; but as long as you are careful with your infinities, the result should still be valid.

First, we find an approximation for $(1-p)^{N-n}$. Taking the log, we get

$$\log\left((1-p)^{N-n}\right) = (N-n)\log(1-p)\approx (N-n)\cdot (-p)$$

Since $N\gg n$, we obtain $(1-p)^{N-n}\approx e^{-Np}$

Next, we approximate the $~^N C_n$ term using Stirling's approximation that $\log N! \approx N\log N - N$ and noting that $n\ll N$

Then

$$\begin{align} \log\left(\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\right) &= N\log N - N - (N-n)\log(N-n) + (N-n) \\
&=N\log N - (N-n)\log(N-n) - n\\
&= N \log N -(N-n)\left(\log(N)+\log\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)\right) -
 n\\
&\approx N\log N -(N-n)\left(\log(N)-\frac{n}{N}\right) - n\\
&\approx n\log N + n -n \log n - n\\
&=n\log(N-n)\end{align}$$

It follows that $\frac{N!}{(N-n)! n!} \approx \frac{N^n}{n!}$

Finally, we note that $pN = \lambda T$, and we get

$$P(n|N,p) = \frac{N^n p^n e^{-Np}}{n!}$$

this easily rearranges to

$$P(n) = \frac{(\lambda T)^n e^{-\lambda T}}{n!}$$

Which is the result we set out to prove.

I made use of [this article](https://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys2150/phys2150_sp16/2016SPOISSONDISTRIBUTION.pdf) to remind me of some of the steps in this.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's actually Stirling's approximation, not Sterling's

Comment: Actually, don't worry if you think that's bad, I spelt Max Planck's name for years the same as the piece of wood or the title of the short film by Eric Sykes. And I know German pretty well (or well enough for much of my communications for my work). I was 50 before I was corrected. That's not the worst of it. I had spent several month long or more visits to Max Planck Institute before I caught on.

Comment: I like this answer. It would be nice to explain why $pN = \lambda T$ is the right way to get from the limit of the discrete binomial distribution to the continuous case. Otherwise it feels a bit hand-wavy.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A^n_t$ be the event: *exactly $n$ point events happened over a time interval $t$*. Then, for small $\Delta t$

$$\begin{align}P(A^n_{t+\Delta t}) &= P( A^n_t \cap A^0_{\Delta t }) + P(A^{n-1}_t \cap A^1_{\Delta t }) \\
&= P(A^n_t) P (A^0_{\Delta t }) + P(A^{n-1}_t )P( A^1_{\Delta t })\\
\end{align}
$$
where we've used independence of occurrence.
Now, defining $p_n(t) \equiv P( A^n_t)$ and 
 $\lambda = \lim_{\Delta t\to 0} p_1(\Delta t)/\Delta t$, and taking the limit for $\Delta t \to 0$ we get

$$ p_n(t+\delta t)=p_n(t)(1 - \lambda \, \delta t) +  p_{n-1}(t) \lambda \, \delta t $$

which leads to the differential equations:

$$p'_n(t)= \begin{cases}
-\lambda ( p_n(t) - p_{n-1}(t) ) & n>0\\
-\lambda  p_n(t) & n=0
\end{cases}$$

with the initial conditions
$$p_n(0)=\begin{cases}0 & n>0\\1 & n=0 \, .\end{cases}$$

The solution is given by the Poisson distribution:

$$p_n(t)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n \exp(-\lambda t)}{n!} \, .$$

Comment: I've learnt two new ways to prove this today, aside from Floris's answer, which was the one I already knew :). Most elegant!