# Are all discovered normal distribution in the physical world a result of central limit theorem?

Tags: statistics

Apart from the wave function in a harmonic well. Are all discovered normal distribution in the physical world a result of central limit theorem?

If it is the case, it may allow some reverse reasoning when we see another normal distribution. Though I guess it is already applied in some domain.

I didn't think it thoroughly, so it may be a nonsense question.

Comment: According to [Cunningham’s Law](https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law), it may be more effective to assert that all natural normal distributions arise from the CLT and see if anyone pushes back with a counterexample.

Comment: What does it mean to discover a normal distribution? I'd rather say that no normal distributions 'exist' in the physical world; they exist in people's heads.

Comment: I suppose then the question means, are there cases where something is well approximated by a normal distribution, that cannot be explained as originating form a large number of independent variables, such that a CLT result could be anticipated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to motivate measurement errors being Gaussian (Jaynes has a whole chapter on them, summarised [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/400858)).

Normal distributions are found elsewhere too. jacob1729 noted one example of a Normal distribution resulting (in thermal equilibrium) from a quadratic energy, a [very important scenario](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem). Another interesting example is a quantum SHO's ground state, which is Normal in either $x$ or $p$-space; the reason is we have to solve $\hat{a}|\psi\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 4):

The $x$ component of the velocity of an ideal gas is normally distributed for entirely different reasons, so no.

Comment: That distribution can’t be explained by applying  the CLT to a large number of random kicks from previous  collisions?

Comment: @Chemomechanics if you can find a sensible way to make that work I'd be interested. It's possible but the barriers I see are: (1) each collision essentially randomises the velocities of both atoms which makes the "many collisions" idea seem wrong and (2) why should that apply to components and not to the speed?

Comment: @Chemomechanics No. If you had a gas of massless particles, the velocity is distributed like $e^{-|v|}$, but your logic would say it's also $e^{-v^2}$.

Comment: For a relativistic treatment, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell–Jüttner_distribution).