# Photon statistics for thermal light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, photons, thermal-radiation

I know that the variance $\Delta^2$ of the number of photons $n$ for thermal light is:

$\Delta^2 n = \bar{n} + \bar{n}^2 \hspace{2 cm} (1) $
where $\bar{n}$ is the average number of photons.

This formula applies for a singlemode of the radiation field. If we have $N_m$ thermal modes of similar frequency we have:

$ \Delta^2 n = \bar{n} + \frac{\bar{n}^2}{N_m} \hspace{1.85 cm} (2) $

Classically we can retrieve that the variance of the intensity $I$ is:

$\Delta^2 I = \bar{I}^2$

and this is compatible with (1) for an high number of photons where the shot noise is negligible. But how can it be compatible with equation (2)?

Comment: In equation (2), does $\bar{n}$ stand for the mean photon number per mode or the mean photon number of all modes together? in the second case, do you assume that all modes have the same mean photon number?

Comment: @A.P. in equation (2), $\bar{n}$ should stand for the mean photon number of all modes together

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtle difference between the photon statistics from a single-mode thermal light source with mean photon number $\bar{n}$ and the photon statistics from $N_m$ *independent* thermal light sources with total mean photon number $\bar{n}$.

In a single-mode thermal light source, the probability distribution of the photon number $n$ is
$$P(n) = \frac{\bar{n}^n}{(\bar{n} + 1)^{n+1}}.$$
It has a variance of
$$\Delta^2 n = \langle n^2 \rangle - \langle n \rangle^2 = \bar{n} + \bar{n}^2,$$
as stated by equation $(1)$ in the question. In the limit of large intensity $\bar{n}^2 \gg \bar{n}$, we can neglect $\bar{n}$ and therefore have
$$\Delta^2n \approx \bar{n}^2 \sim \bar{I}^2.$$

If you average over several independent thermal light sources, the fluctuations will wash out. In a moment where one light source has a high intensity, another one might have a low intensity and vice versa. Let's say each independent light source has a mean photon number of $\bar{n_i} = \bar{n} / N_m$. Each has a variance of
$$\Delta^2 n_i = \bar{n_i} + \bar{n_i}^2.$$
Since the different modes are independent, the overall variance is simply the sum of the individual variances
$$\Delta^2 n = \sum_i \Delta^2 n_i = N_m \left( \bar{n_i} + \bar{n_i}^2 \right) = \bar{n} + \frac{\bar{n}^2}{N_m}.$$
This is equation $(2)$ in the question. If you now take the classical limit by using a large number of independent thermal light sources $N_m$, the result is
$$\Delta^2 n \approx \bar{n} \sim \bar{I},$$
like for a light source with Poissonian statistics! The reason is, as stated above, the independence of the different modes. Therefore, the photons from different modes arrive independently on the detector. [DanielSank wrote a nice answer how this leads to a Poissonian distribution.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/372602/169454)